# Do I have to store ISODate in JSON for mongodb to work?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have inserted a document into mongodb that looks like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a0a532e09c1c52be0c14012"), "tranid" :     
"414d", "startTime" : "2017-11-13T21:16:50.994Z","status" : "0" }
```

The "2017-11-13T21:16:50.994Z" is exactly how i receive into my java code as string, i just use

```
Document doc = Document.parse(jsonData);
```

to parse the string into Document and store in mongodb. Now i am trying to search
for documents greater than a certain date time like this

```
db.collection.find({"startTime":{$gte:new ISODate("2017-11-13T21:00:00.000Z")});

also tried

db.collection.find({"startTime":{$gte:new ISODate("2017-11-13T21:16:00Z")});
```

neither one seems to work. I did some look up online and saw that the JSON data needs to be ISODate, Should i convert the incoming startTime into ISODate first and then do the Document parse?

Comment: Your current dates are "strings" so you can do `.find({"startTime":{$gte: "2017-11-13" } })`. But you **"should"** convert them, as they take less storage and are far more useful that way. Anything supplied as [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) will be stored as a BSON Date within MongoDB, and can also be subsequently queried that way.

Comment: this worked...db.logger.find({"startTime":{$gte: ("2017-11-13T21:17:00.000Z"),$lte: ("2017-11-13T21:17:55.000Z")}}).count();

Comment: It sure does, as the string representation is comparable, too. However, as Neil correctly pointed out, that takes up a lot more space and makes the field unusable for date based aggregations.